Altium 3D component causing collision on PCB even though component should sit underneath
I would like to accomplish something like the following on my PCB for a current sense resistor:

However, now that I am using a new shunt resistor and imported the change, I now receive a bunch of collision warnings as such:

Any idea what could be leading my astray here? Do I need to somehow put an offset distance on the 3d model in the footprint? Thanks

How about a top and side view after update?

Hi. Altium can tell you between what parts the Collisions are concerned. IN the Panels tab select: PCB Rules and Violations

I suspect you have your "Component Height" rule set too low. Change it to more than the height of the component.

I solved this issue by changing the "standoff height" in the footprint properties such that the top of my through hole pins corresponding to the footprint "cutout"



+1 That's a huge offset (41mm), the original model is a bit strange- not uncommon, sadly. What's the point of having 4 sense terminals (plus 4 mechanical plus two power) terminals on the resistor, improved accuracy?
